# Reading/parsing a copybook in text format using JRecord, the builder seems to think it's an XML file

Tags: java, cobol, copybook, jrecord

I'm trying to read,parse a copybook in .txt format using [JRecord](https://jrecord.sourceforge.net/) and then process a binary file using the copybook schema.

When I try to read the binary file using `schemaBuilder.newReader(binaryFile)`, it gives me an exception saying :-

```
CopybookFile.txt:1:1:net.sf.JRecord.Common.RecordException : Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

The nested exception seems to be a SAXParseException with the same message.

I notice that while using the IOBUilder with the copybook file, the loader seems to be an XMlCopyBookLoader and not a cobol file loader. **How do I make the IOBuilder recognise that I'm trying to parse a txt/cbl file?**

Minimal sample below :

```
ICobolIOBuilder schemaBuilder = JRecordInterface1.COBOL.newIOBuilder(copyBookFilePathWithDotTxt).setDialect(1).setFont("cp037").setDropCopyBookNameFromFields(true); // using the debugger, I see that schemaBuilder.loader is an  XMLCopyBookLoader and schemaBuilder is of type CblIOBuilderMultiSchema
try { 
AbstractLineReader reader = schemaBuilder.newReader(binaryFilePath);
} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

I have tried using the same file with .cbl extension as well. I also know that it's able to read the file because if I put xml content in there it seems to atleast move till the first invalid character. i.e line after XML.

java version - 8

JRecord version 0.81.5

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? https://jrecord.sourceforge.net/JRecord04.html#Header_10 If this allows you to solve the problem: please answer your own question and accept it as "works for me", outlining where the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

From the bugs section in the JRecord source forge, it was infered that cb2xml is to be added as a dependency separately sometime between 0.80.5 and 0.81.5 . On adding it I was able to parse the copybook correctly.

Comment: I suggest to mark this answer as "works for me" - this way it is clear that the issue is solved (and one can find the solution here)